# How Traction differs from Road friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, terminology

I am an aspiring mechanical engineer & me n my team are going to manufacture a buggy for which i am going to design & manufacture the braking system. 
I have a problem in understanding The basic concept of traction & how it differs from friction.

Comment: They are the same. See https://intblog.onspot.com/what-is-traction-friction-and-road-grip

Comment: Thankyou so muchh!!